# Python regex for Parsing Microsoft Word Docx

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to parse and extract text from a Microsoft Word document and I've run into a few problems. I'm using `re.findall` and somehow I'm getting duplicate extractions. For example, `Company Name` is in the extracted list twice, even though it only appears once in the document. Secondly, I'm getting unwanted characters back, like `You&#8217;re` instead of just `You're`. Finally, with what I'm trying to do I'm wondering if the path I'm on is even the most efficient way of going about this. Any advice is appreciated.

Here's a small sample of what I'm trying to extract:

```
<ns0:t>You&#8217;re currently utilizing two canonical tags per page, which needs to be reduced to just one.</ns0:t><ns0:r><ns0:t xml:space="preserve">As an </ns0:t></ns0:r><ns0:proofErr ns0:type="gramStart" /><ns0:r><ns0:t>example</ns0:t></ns0:r><ns0:proofErr ns0:type="gramEnd" /><ns0:r><ns0:t xml:space="preserve"> here are two canonicals..
```

Most of what I need falls between `<ns0:t> </ns0:t>`. However, there's also `<ns0:t xml:space="preserve">` that I must account for as well.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

doc = zipfile.ZipFile('doc-template.docx').read('word/document.xml')
root = ET.fromstring(doc)
string_doc = ET.tostring(root)
re.findall(r'<ns0:t>([^<]*)<', string_doc.decode('utf-8'))
```

Eventually I'm trying to get to the point where I can accomplish the following, except within a dictionary comprehension:

```
paragraph1 = "text from paragraph1"
paragraph2 = "text from paragraph2"
```

etc
Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you attempting to manually parse the document? Packages like `docx` provide tools for easily extracting and manipulating text in a document as well as lower level xml manipulation.

Comment: @Locke initially I was trying to parse the pdf version of the file with `PyPDF2` but it was extremely inconsistent and kept leaving out words. There were also a lot of issues with it putting spaces where they didn't belong. So I thought it would be better to leave the file as a docx and manually parse it myself. However, if the `docx` package is more reliable, then I'll certainly give it a shot.

Comment: I'm getting empty strings with `docx`  `document.paragraphs[0].text` or through a for loop, still does the same.

Comment: To solve **You&#8217;re** problem try: `ET.tosrting(root,encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: To make your regex catch both cases try: `'(?:<ns0:t>|<ns0:r><ns0:t xml:space="preserve">)([^<]*)'`